# SQL Server Does Not Use Index

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I have a `Material` table with two columns that are indexed.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [MaterialName_PartType_idx] ON [dbo].[Material]
(
    [MaterialName] ASC,
    [PartType] ASC
)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [PartType_idx] ON [dbo].[Material]
(
    [PartType] ASC
)
```

When I query

```
SELECT PartType FROM Material
```

it uses Index Scan, but when I query

```
SELECT MaterialName FROM Material
```

it uses Table Scan.

```
SELECT MaterialName, PartType FROM Material
```

also uses Table Scan

Both `PartType` and `MaterialName` are of type `VARCHAR(50)`.

Why would it not use Index Scan? I am using SQL Server 2000.

Comment: it might be because of variety of the values in those fields. I think you have a few PartType so it uses index scan and you have more variation of MaterialType so it prefers to use Table Scan, because it doesn't make any difference

Comment: What does the rest of the table look like (a table definition with relevant indexes would do)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stock answer: it depends.

How wide are the columns? How "full" are they? How many columns are in the table? How many rows?

If there are just the two columns, and if Material is a varchar(100) that is often populated with 25 or more characters, and if PartType is an integer,
and if there are thousands and thousands of rows [note that that is 4 ifs] then:

- On selecting just the PartType, the SQL optimizer realizes that it'd be more efficient to read the index (4 bytes per row) than the table, and does so
- On selecting Material, the SQL optimizer realizes that it's reading pretty much the whole table--no time saved reading the index. (I'm not entirely convinced by that, but I'm avoiding tossing in more IFs, such as are there other indexes, is there a clustered index, and so forth)
- On selecting Material *and* PartType, the SQL same logic applies, only moreso.
- A key factor, you do not have and `order by` clause--you're just asking for all the data in whatever order is most convenient for SQL to return it in. If you `order by` Material, odds are extremely good SQL will use that index.

Comment: (to emphasize the order by clause comment...)   SELECT MaterialName
     , PartType
  FROM Material 
 ORDER BY MaterialName
        , PartType

Comment: It's a small table (~ 3000 rows).  Both MaterialName and PartType are of type varchar.  When I add an order by clause, it makes use of the index.